# One of my colleagues has possible problems. Should I share my thought with anyone?

Tags: work-environment

How should one deal best with a colleague, who's having some possible problems ?

One of my colleagues behaves very weird in and outside work.I've heard a lot of complaining in the office regarding him. Up to now, this phenomenon is widely known in the company.
He is also kind of aggressive and often behaves abnormally. 
It's hard to have a conversation at all, but when you do, no normal person would say anything like this.

Unfortunately, we have some common interests outside of work and my complain would be not very useful because the would think it's on personal motives.

How can and should I talk with someone from the management?

EDIT 1:

OK, I'm not a doctor, I can not give any diagnosis, but something is wrong.

EDIT 2:

I don't evaluate anyone's performance as well. The problem is with behavior that is a problem.

Comment: Do the 'mental problems' affect his work performance, is he still doing a good job? It seems like it may be affecting other people in the office, but without defining 'mental problems' or 'behaves abnormally' it's difficult to offer advice.

Comment: If he's not underperforming in a way that is affecting you, you should stay away from this. I don't think it's recommended to complain to a manager about things that are not affecting you, even less if you are going to say he has "mental problems". Keep your relationship strictly professional if he can't have a nice, polite conversation. If he's unable to do that, you should then inform your manager about him not being cooperative, not "being mental ill".

Comment: You should steer clear of diagnosing a cloleagues state of mind. If you wish to discuss issues with a manager stick to facts about actual things they have done.

Comment: If there is an issue with your friend's performance at work, I'm sure your managers would have already realised it.  And unless he is doing something illegal then I can't see what you actually have to tell.  I would suggest leaving it alone.

Comment: If the employee is having issues, management may already be aware - in which case it's nobody's business. Additionally, if you're suggesting someone with an unpredictable and aggressive behavior, I'd not poke the bear on that one.

Comment: give some concrete examples of the things he may be saying plz.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Speculating about the mental health of anyone is one of the surest ways to nuke your credibility both with your management and with us. You are not an expert on mental illness so don't even go there. Because both your management and us will recognize that you are speculating about things you know nothing about and everything you say from this point forward is suspect.

If you have a problem with your colleague's actions and words:

1. Make a representative list of what he said or did that you believe was egregious, state in what way the egregiousness materially impacted YOUR - not someone else's - ability to perform your duties or your ability to interact with him so that you could perform your duties. Include date, time, location and witnesses for each incident you are reporting. You don't need  to make a huge list - let's say, five representative or one-off incidents that illustrutate what you are talking about. Then make an initial appointment with either boss or HR to discuss the issue.
2. Again, stay away from any mention of mental illness, it's not your call to make nor any of your business. On the other hand, if your colleague is having a meltdown instead of discussing a project with you, then his behavior is concerning.

If you have a point, HR will ultimately have to sort out the personnel issue of your colleague's behavior and decide what to do about him. In fact, that's their job. And they know how to do their job in a way that preserves everyone's confidentiality.